# wkhtmltopdf : failing when run through C# Code

Tags: c#, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I am using wkhtmltopdf to create PDF from given HTML. Basically we have some graphs/chart based reports, so we create HTML using our C# code and then use WKHTMLTOPDF to create PDF. It was working fine, but yesterday it stop to creating PDF. I try to debug and process works without any error or message. Just we didn't get PDF as output. I try to run and use Wkhtmltopdf.exe from command line and it does create PDF with all verbose as expected.

my Code is

```
public static bool HTMLtoPDF(string HTMLPath, string PDFPath, PageOrientation orientation)
{
    using (System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process())
    {
        string dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Vikasumit.VSCommon)).Location) + "\\wkhtmltopdf\\";

        proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = dir;
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = dir + "wkhtmltopdf.exe";
        if (orientation == PageOrientation.Landscape)
        {
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = " --page-width 11in --page-height 8.5in --margin-left 0.5cm --margin-right 0 --margin-top 1.25cm --margin-bottom 0 " + HTMLPath + "  " + PDFPath;
        }
        else
        {
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = " --page-width 8.5in --page-height 11in --margin-left 0.5cm --margin-right 0 --margin-top 1.25cm --margin-bottom 0 " + HTMLPath + "  " + PDFPath;
        }
        proc.Start();
        proc.WaitForExit();
        string result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        proc.Close();
        proc.Dispose();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Indeed this works fine, This code works fine for PDF with one or 2 pages, but this report has 800 page [about 1.2MB HTML file and output file from cmmand line goes around 2.3MB.]

Any idea what might be going wrong in here? It is memory assign to task is limited or what? Thanks.

Comment: What values do PDFpath and HTMLPath get? Also, why do you result false always?

Comment: PDFPath and HTMLPath get Complete physical path of input and output files, return false was part of error, I had try catch before and just leave something there. But the above code works for small files with 2-10 page of report but fails for 800 page reports. and that is my main problem.

Comment: Argh what an annoying issue :). Does StandardError contain anything?

Comment: no mate, if error was there, I might have solve it by now :).

Answer (score 1):

I use the Rotativa nuget component to wrap the wkhtmltopdf executable in my web app. I do not save to file, but rather use it to download pdf for client...

1) They do suggest to add the ignore load error switch (not sure what it covers)
           --load-error-handling ignore

2) Since your writing to disk, and it only happens on large files, is there a disk space issue?

Comment: no I have 50-60GB storage available on disk and around 1GB RAM/memory available, so nothing like disk space error